# How to make a header fixed but without it being outside of flow?

Tags: css

So I have hero and header components in react. I made header fixed but that way it goes outside of flow, so hero components overlays it. It looks like this:
[image]

I want to make the header fixed, but also make it be on top of the page. The hero component's position is static as usual.

Header css:

```
    @include flex(center, space-between);
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: $header-height;
```

Hero css:

```
 @include flex(center, center);
    flex-direction: column;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    background-color: $body-bg;
```

I know it looks like a basic thing to do, but I can't figure it out, I tried making header relative, but that way it's not fixed. And making hero relative makes it overlay header.

Comment: take a look to sticky position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to nav section.

```
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
```

Comment: ohh, i did it before and it didn't work, but now it works. but isn't `position: sticky` less supported by browsers?

Comment: yah there are some browsers still doesn't support it 
https://caniuse.com/?search=position%3A%20sticky

Comment: There's an alternative. you can see here-
https://codepen.io/njmsaikat/pen/eYeJwPN

Comment: thanks! in that case i have to add margin-top, but it works at least